# What are ResourceReferences in Wicket, and how do they work?

Tags: java, wicket, resourcereference

I have seen examples containing things like this:

```
mountSharedResource("/images/logo.gif", new ResourceReference(ImageScope.class,
  "logo.gif").getSharedResourceKey());

mountSharedResource("/resource",
  Application.class.getName() + "/" + resourceKey);
```

But the Javadoc says this for the constructor:

```
ResourceReference(java.lang.Class<?> scope, java.lang.String name);
```

So when you create a `ResourceReference`, you give it a class. Why? Usually you would want either global scope or the scope of the `ResourceReference` object you have just created, no?

Also, what is `name`? Is it the `sharedResourceKey`? If not, where does the `resourceKey` come from? How is it generated, and why isn't it the name? Or is `name` looked up on the classpath, and magically loaded (assuming that there is only one file with that name on the classpath; what happens if there are multiple?)? If it does load a file with that name, why doesn't it say so in the Javadoc?

How do you actually assign a physcial resource to this `ResourceReference`? There is a `getResource()`, but they seem to have missed out `setResource()`. If you have, say, an image file in your `webapp` dir, how do you "attach" the reference to the file, its path, or even a byte stream of the file's contents? If there were a way to read resources in the webapp, this might be useful, but you can't; it's only in the classpath.

I would love to be able to "mount" the contents of, say, `webapp/games/someGame.swf` so that the SWF in a webapp can be accessed by the Wicket pages, or just get some kind of handle on them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To expand on Andrew's answer:

A `ResourceReference` per se is nothing but a *reference* to a resource available through `SharedResources`. Any kind of `Resource` that you add to `SharedResources` (usually done in your `Application#init()`) has a name that you define. Any `Component` that uses a resource can then refer to this shared resource through a `ResourceReference` with that name - hence the parameter being called "name". In this case the scope parameter (the class) is not needed.

This is the general case, to refer to *any* kind of Resource.

The case shown in your and Andrew's examples is a more special case:  Your `ResourceReference`'s `name` does not refer to a `Resource` previously added to `SharedResources`. Here a so-called `PackageResource` is lazily initialized and added to `SharedResources`.

`PackageResource` is what actually does the whole "load-file-from-classpath" stuff.

So if you want to just refer to a file like an image from your classpath, Andrew's example is simply a very useful shortcut to avoid creating that `PackageResource` yourself. As noted above, there is more to `ResourceReference` than just that :-)

Answer (score 10):

A resource such as an image is usually associated with a particular web page. So it makes sense to locate that image in the same place as the Java and HTML files.

The class parameter serves as a base from which to lookup your resource. The second parameter to the ResourceReference constructor is the name of the resource, relative to the directory containing the class.

So for example you could have -

```
new ResourceReference(AClass.class, "sub/directory/image.jpg");
```

You assign a physical resource by simply placing that resource in the correct directory when your application is deployed.

There's a chapter on using resources in the book "Wicket in Action".

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, thanks!  So then the parameter name is not correct: it should be called "path" or "filename".  If the path is relative to the location of the class (presumably /com/something/package) how does one refer to the files in the webapp, which is where they are always held (for us anyway).  This is the crux - we want to get a handle on a swf file in the games directory of the webapp, and havent been able to find any way to do this: hence the initial interest in ResourceReference.

Comment: Correct, the 'name' is a path relative to the location of the 'scope' (class). This is determined by the class package name, as to where it physically lives on your filesystem. The name parameter doesn't support clever things like using '../..' notation to navigate further up the directory tree. So your resource must be relative to the location of the class file.
BTW I would really recommend getting hold of that book I mentioned, it's very good.

Comment: Note [ResourceReference](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket/1.5-M1/wicket-1.5-M1-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/wicket/request/resource/ResourceReference.html) is an abstract class and cannot be instantiated.