# Simple ImageButton

Tags: wicket

I want to make a simple ImageButton from an existing HTML markup:

```
<input type="image" wicket:id="enter" src="images/enter.jpg" />
```

*images* dir is in the root of the webapp.
Java code is:

```
add(new ImageButton("enter"));
```

But image isn't displayed.
What's the most easiest way to make it work?

After further investigation I see that Wicket modifies *src* attribute:

```
src="resources/com.mycomp...Class/images/enter_en.jpg
```

It would be great to leave *src* attribute unmodified.

Comment: If your image is a static file, a simple `Button` will do. ImageButton is for cases where the image in question is a Wicket resource itself.

Comment: Thanks! You should write it as an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So here's now my comment in answer form:

If the image is a static file, a simple `Button` will do.

`ImageButton` is only for cases where the image in question is a Wicket resource itself. This is quite useful if your image is dynamically generated, comes from a database or if your images are locale/language dependent.

Comment: Can you give an example ? (How do you associate the image to the button)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
add(new ImageButton("enter", new ResourceReference(AClass.class, "images/enter.jpg");
```

Note that enter.jpg must be placed in an 'images' directory relative to the location of your AClass file.

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6685608/what-are-resourcereferences-in-wicket-and-how-do-they-work) for more information on ResrouceReference

Looking at the source for ImageButton, I also see the constructor

```
ImageButton(String, Resource)
```

which may be worth investigating further.

Comment: Moving image into another directory is one of the latest things I want to do. It would be great if ImageResource/ResourceReference could point to the current location or even just leave "src" attribute as it had been set in the markup.